# $\iint \limits_{x^2+y^2\leq a^2}x^my^ndxdy=0$

Tags: integration

I tried to prove that

$$\iint \limits_{x^2+y^2\leq a^2}x^my^ndxdy=0$$

if m and n are positive integers and at least one of these is odd.

Could you give me some idea of ​​how to prove this?

Comment: Polar coordinates is a possibility.

Comment: If say $n$ is odd, then the integral over the upper half of the disk is the negative of the integral over the lower half, since $(-y)^n=-y^n.$

Answer (score 5):

Suppose first that $m$ is odd. Substitution by $(x,y)=(-z,y)$ gives $$dxdy=|-1|dzdy=dzdy$$ and 
$$
I=\iint \limits_{x^2+y^2\leq a^2}x^my^ndxdy=\iint \limits_{z^2+y^2\leq a^2}(-z)^my^ndzdy=-\iint \limits_{z^2+y^2\leq a^2}z^my^ndzdy=-I.
$$ Thus $I=0$. The case where $n$ is odd can be addressed in the same manner by making substitution $(x,y)=(x,-z)$.

Comment: Much more elegant than my suggestion. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Change to polar coordinates to write it as $$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^a(r\cos(\theta))^m(r\sin(\theta))^mrdrd\theta=\left(\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^m(\theta)\sin^n(\theta)d\theta\right)\left(\int_0^a r^{n+m+1}dr\right)$$
and just focus on the $\theta$ integral.